# Who was the previous holder of the Necrosword?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, thor-love-and-thunder

In the opening scene of *Thor: Love and Thunder*, Gorr finds Rapu, who was celebrating the death of the Necrosword holder. Later,  Rapu disappoints Gorr and Gorr kills him.

Who was this previous holder of the Necrosword? Was any backstory given to him, or is his name even known?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the MCU he doesn't have a name (or at least no name given in the film), but the studio responsible for his concept art dubbed him **[The Dark Shadow Lord](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_Shadow_Lord_(Earth-199999))**

[image]

He appears to be based on the evil god [**Knull**](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Knull_(Earth-616)). Gorr inherits the necrosword from him in the comic [*Thor: God of Thunder #6*](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thor:_God_of_Thunder_Vol_1_6), on which the movie is loosely based.

[image]